# Display description below menu item in drupal 8

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, drupal-8, theming

I am trying to display menu description below Menu title in drupal 8. I have created menu--main.html.twig, but it don't get any value for localized_options when I debugged items. How can I achieve this in drupal 8?

Answer (score 10):

The plugin definition (and the menu description) is inside the object `original_link`.

You can add

```
{% if item.original_link.pluginDefinition.description %}
    <span class="navigation__link-description">{{ item.original_link.pluginDefinition.description }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

and this should display your menu description.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:`{{ item.original_link.getDescription() }}`

Answer (score 1):

`{{ item.original_link.pluginDefinition.description }}` does not translate the description

`{{ item.original_link.getDescription() }}` translates the description

Answer (score 0):

I use "simplify menu" module for menu render:

```
{# Get menu items #}
{% set items = simplify_menu('main') %}

{# Iterate menu tree #}
<nav class="navigation__items">
  {% for menu_item in items.menu_tree %}
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="{{ menu_item.url }}">{{ menu_item.text }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

Using the example, I thought it would be easy, tried {{ menu_item. description }} but it didn't work

**UPD:**
Use patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify_menu/issues/2891950#comment-13648866